# Репликация баз Firebird

Tags: firebird

Есть 2 сервера на обоих стоит firebird, на одном v.1.5(сервер А) на другом v.2.5(сервера Б). Как можно сделать репликацию базы с А на Б ?

Comment: Использование Firebird критично? Почему не использовать PostgreSQL с его слоником?

Comment: База уже давно готова и забита с 2008 года. Тем более если перейду на другую базу и даже перенесу данные переписывать программу под эту БД не вариант, и уж очень мне нравятся фишки в Firebird'е. А PostgreSQL ни разу не работал, тем более читал что она более сложна.   Но даже если так есть вариант просто синхронизации данных (добавили внесли что то в исходной базе это же добавилось в резервной).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как по мне, простейший вариант такой: На сервере А сделать Windows Task или CRON task (В зависимоти от того какая ОС), которая будет запускать gbak на интересующей базе и затем заливать бекап на сервер Б в определенную папку расшаренную через Windows Share/Samba/NFS (опять же в зависимоти от ОС). На сервере Б аналогично таск который будет подхватывать новые бекапы и применять их к базе. Вот не помню только, если gbak поддерживает дифференциальный бекап, то можно делать из для сокращения объема файла бекапа.

Comment: Нет это глупо. какая же это репликация тогда, надо по умному всё делать. В принципе нашел одну бесплатную программу FBReplicator но что то в ней разобраться не могу и документации к ней нет.

Comment: Ну в таком случае лучше уж потратиться на платный IBReplicator или разобраться с DBRE http://dbre.sourceforge.net/ru/